# Setting a custom Content-Type response header in Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type

First let me clarify that I do not access to the server to which I am making the ajax request. So I cannot change the response headers on the server.

Secondly I want the response to contain an additional header:

`"Content-Type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"`

So that my response can be decoded properly. I read in another answer on Stack Overflow that browser does not care about the Content-Type header. It only matters at the application level so that application can detect and decode response properly.

So I am wondering that there should be a way to set this response header before the response is parsed by Javascript. I know for sure that if this header is set then the response is being parsed properly otherwise it garbles some of the characters.

Currently I am using vanilla Javascript (i.e. XMLHttpRequest) for making this call so it will great if someone can tell me how to achieve this using with only vanilla Javascript. Although I can switch to using JQuery also if required.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after looking at the w3 documentation for XMLHttpRequest. This is the code I ended up using:

```
var http =  new XMLHttpRequest()
http.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

This will essentially do what I was trying to achieve i.e. Set a custom value for Content-Type response header